Min $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{99}\frac{x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2+1}{x_i x_{i+1}}$ where $\{x_k\}_1^{100}$ is a permutation of $1, \cdots, 100$
I encountered a Math Olympiad Question which I do not know how to do

Let $x_1, \cdots, x_{100}$ be a permutation of $1, \cdots, 100$, find the minimum value of

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2+1}{x_i x_{i+1}}\tag{1}$$
I suspect it should be $x_i=i$ and it may use the rearrangement inequality, but I could not figure out the details.

Note: This argument is wrong. @FD_bfa pointed out in a comment that the permutation $x_i=i$ maximizes, not minimizes, the red part below. I'll leave this answer for now just in case there's a useful idea here that someone else can use, and I mention a possible fix in the comments but don’t want to get it wrong again yet.]
The permutation that minimizes $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2+1}{x_i x_{i+1}}$$ must also minimize $$S-198
=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\left(\frac{x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2+1}{x_i x_{i+1}}-2\right)\\
=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\left(\frac{x_i^2+x_{i+1}^2+1-2x_ix_{i+1}}{x_i x_{i+1}}\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\left(x_i-x_{i+1}+1\right)^2-2(x_i-x_{i+1})}{x_i x_{i+1}}\\
=\sum_{i=1}^{99}\left(\frac{\left(x_i-x_{i+1}+1\right)^2}{x_i x_{i+1}}-{2\over x_{i+1}}+{2\over x_{i}}\right)
=\color{red}{{2\over x_1}-{2\over x_{100}}}+\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\left(x_i-x_{i+1}+1\right)^2}{x_i x_{i+1}}}.$$
For the permutation $x_i=i$, this gives
$$S-198=2-{1\over50}+\sum_1^{99}{0\over x_ix_{i+1}},$$
and for any other permutation, both the $\color{red}{\mbox{red}}$ and $\color{blue}{\mbox{blue}}$ parts are larger [Note: This is incorrect for the red part, as noted above an in a comment].
Thus the minimum value of $S$ is $200-{1\over50}=199.98.$

How is the red part larger for any other permutation?

Shouldn’t you have $x_i = 100-i$ to minimise the red part? At the moment you are maximising it.

Aargh, I think you're right. I have to say, this seemed too slick. I'll add a note at the top but won't delete the answer, since maybe there's a useful idea here, still...

Before I fix this too quickly, will it work to change $$\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\left(x_i-x_{i+1}+1\right)^2-2(x_i-x_{i+1})}{x_i x_{i+1}}$$ to $$\sum_{i=1}^{99}\frac{\left(x_{i+1}-x_i+1\right)^2-2(x_{i+1}-x_i)}{x_i x_{i+1}}$$?

Proof.
Remark. I learned this trick from others.
Let
$$S_n(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) 
:= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{x_i^2 + x_{i+1}^2 + 1}{x_i x_{i+1}}.$$
We have
$S_n(1, 2, \cdots, n) = 2n - 2/n$.
If $n = 2, 3, 4$, it is easy to obtain $S_n(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) \ge 2n - 2/n$.
Fact 1. Let $n \ge 4$. Let $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ be a permutation of $1, 2, \cdots, n$. Then $S_n(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) \ge 2n - 2/n$.
(The proof of Fact 1 is given at the end.)
By Fact 1, we are done.

Proof of Fact 1.
We use the Mathematical Induction.
If $n = 4$, it is true.
Assume that it is true for $n$ ($n\ge 4$).
For $n + 1$, assume $x_k = n + 1$. We split into three cases.
(i) If $2 \le k \le n$, by the inductive hypothesis, we have
\begin{align*}
 &S_{n+1}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n+1})\\
 ={}& S_n(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{k-1}, x_{k+1}, \cdots, x_{n+1})\\
 &\qquad + \frac{x_{k-1}^2 +x_k^2 + 1}{x_{k-1}x_k} + \frac{x_k^2 +x_{k+1}^2 + 1}{x_kx_{k+1}} - \frac{x_{k-1}^2 +x_{k+1}^2 + 1}{x_{k-1}x_{k+1}}\\
 \ge{}& 2n - 2/n + \frac{x_{k-1}^2 +(n+1)^2 + 1}{x_{k-1}(n+1)} + \frac{(n+1)^2 +x_{k+1}^2 + 1}{(n+1)x_{k+1}} - \frac{x_{k-1}^2 +x_{k+1}^2 + 1}{x_{k-1}x_{k+1}}\\
 \ge{}& 2n - 2/n + \frac{2n^2 + 2n + 2}{n(n+1)}\\
 ={}& 2(n+1) - 2/(n+1)
\end{align*}
where we use
$$\frac{x_{k-1}^2 +(n+1)^2 + 1}{x_{k-1}(n+1)} + \frac{(n+1)^2 +x_{k+1}^2 + 1}{(n+1)x_{k+1}} - \frac{x_{k-1}^2 +x_{k+1}^2 + 1}{x_{k-1}x_{k+1}}\ge \frac{2n^2 + 2n + 2}{n(n+1)}$$
which can be written as ($a := x_{k-1}, b := x_{k+1}$; $1 \le a, b \le n$)
\begin{align*}
 \frac{2n^3 + (-2b^2 + 3b - 4)n + 2b}{n(n^2-1)b} + \frac{(n + 1 - b)(n - 1 - a)(an + bn - a + b - 1)}{ab(n^2 - 1)}\ge 0
\end{align*}
which is true (easy).
(ii) If $k = n+1$, by the inductive hypothesis, we have
\begin{align*}
 &S_{n+1}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n+1})\\
 ={}& S_n(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) + \frac{x_n^2 +x_{n+1}^2 + 1}{x_nx_{n+1}}\\
 \ge{}& 2n - 2/n + \frac{x_n^2 + (n + 1)^2 + 1}{x_n(n + 1)}\\
 ={}& 2n - 2/n + \frac{n^2 + (n + 1)^2 + 1}{n(n + 1)} + \frac{(n - x_n)(n^2 - nx_n + 2n + 2)}{x_n n ( n + 1)}\\
 \ge{}&2n - 2/n + \frac{n^2 + (n + 1)^2 + 1}{n(n + 1)}\\
 ={}& 2(n+1) - 2/(n+1)
\end{align*}
where we use $x_n \le n$.
(iii) If $k = 1$, by the inductive hypothesis, we have
\begin{align*}
 &S_{n+1}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n+1})\\
 ={}& S_n(x_2, \cdots, x_{n+1}) + \frac{x_1^2 +x_2^2 + 1}{x_1x_2}\\
 \ge{}& 2n - 2/n + \frac{(n+1)^2 + x_2^2 + 1}{(n+1)x_2}\\
 ={}& 2n - 2/n + \frac{n^2 + (n + 1)^2 + 1}{n(n + 1)} + \frac{(n - x_2)(n^2 - nx_2 + 2n + 2)}{x_2 n ( n + 1)}\\
 \ge{}&2n - 2/n + \frac{n^2 + (n + 1)^2 + 1}{n(n + 1)}\\
 ={}& 2(n+1) - 2/(n+1)
\end{align*}
where we use $x_2 \le n$.
Thus, it is true for $n + 1$.
We are done.

Heuristic Argument :
When we check the fraction , we see that it has 3 Parts :
$A=x_{i}/x_{i+1}$
$B=x_{i+1}/x_{i}$
$C=1/x_{i}x_{i+1}$
It has a number $A$ & the reciprocal $B$ , which is minimized when the number is $\approx 1$ , to give $\approx 1+1 \approx 2$
That requires that $x_{i} \approx x_{i+1}$
Hence $x_{i}+1 = x_{i+1}$
Hence $x_{i} = i$
Here $C$ is already very small , hence that Permutation will give over-all minimum.
We can check with $(1,2,3)$ , which gives smaller total than $(1,3,2)$ , which gives smaller total than $(3,1,2)$
Alternate Heuristic Argument :
Basically , when we have a Permutation , we can reorder the numbers such that it tends to "Natural Order" $x_{i} = i$ to make the Sum smaller.
We can not reorder the numbers further when "Natural Order" $x_{i} = i$ is achieved.
